# How can I fetch the selected view?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

How can I fetch the selected view (red underline) and its result and access this is a web resource (custom chart that has a web resource)?

[image]

I want to make custom chart. And for my "Grid Assets" I have created a chart by exporting an area chart, modifying the xml to use a webresource and then import it. It work. However, I dont have user context . Surly I cant with javascript use the SDK and poll all of my "Grid Assets" but I want it to work in context with the selected view.

The current view "Active Grid Assets" has over 5000 elements, and I have created several other views so want I am trying to accomplish is that when the user changes the view, the view result (data) is changed. The webresource picks up on this and visualize this in the HTML5 chart.

So bottom line, how can I get the selected view? And how can I get the data result of that view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reread the question and deleted my other answer, which was geared toward web resources on a form.

Since you are working on the view screen rather than a form I am unaware of any supported way to add a web resource to the chart pane and hook into the change of the view.

If anyone else has a way to do this, either supported or unsupported, I'd be interested to learn more.